# Replacing a gradle dependency in Flutter library

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm writing a Flutter app that uses the "flutter_reactive_ble" plugin. That plugin, in turn, uses "RxAndroidBle" java library. I have made a small change to RxAndroidBle, and it compiles into .aar files. But my Gradle-fu is insufficient to figure out how to tell flutter_reactive_ble to use my version instead of retrieving the latest version from the web. I'd be happiest if I could just point to my local .aar files, but if I have to serve them from my own site, that would be OK as well.

After building my app, the "android/app/build.gradle" file ends with:

```
dependencies {
    . . .
    implementation "com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.11.1"
}
```

I assume that's what I'll need to change, but nothing I can find in the Gradle docs look like what I need.

Comment: You could vendor the package and change the dependency in its gradle

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said. I just haven't been able to figure out how--I'm not a gradle guy and the documents are incomprehensible.

Comment: If you fork the repo and change the dependency [here](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/blob/master/packages/reactive_ble_mobile/android/build.gradle) in the plugin itself, it should work

Comment: OK, no problem forking the repo, but the dependency line in this file says "implementation 'com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.12.1", and I assume it still has to because the code is still the "com.polidea..." package even on my site. How do I tell gradle to physically get it from github.com/lcrocker/RxAndroidBle ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fork `flutter_reactive_ble`, go to `build.gradle` and remove [this line](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/blob/master/packages/reactive_ble_mobile/android/build.gradle#L98) then open android studio and open  `File > Project Structure > Dependencies`:

[image]

Then Add your module library(.aar files you built):

[image]

in the end, android studio will add this line to `build.gradle`:

```
implementation(project(path: ":example-library"))
```

Make sure to use `flutter_reactive_ble` from your git repository inside your app, in your `.yaml` file add:

```
  flutter_reactive_ble:
    git:
      url: your/git/flutter_reactive_ble/repository/url
      ref: tag or commit id
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. What I actually ended up doing to get the code out was actually copying the updated AARs into the local Gradle cache before building the next stage. Ugly, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need fork repo first

And .yaml set like this
([read this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages))

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your try, but flutter_reactive_ble *is* a plugin, and doesn't have a pubspec.yaml. The dependency on rxandroidbleis buried inside a build.gradle in a subdirectory.

Comment: It mean your app .yaml, follow this step

1. Fork flutter_reactive_ble 

2. Set your .arr to gradle in your forked flutter_reactive_ble repo 

3. Add your forked flutter_reactive_ble repo into your root app .yaml

Comment: Exactly. It's that step 2 that I'm trying to do. I've read the docs and tried different methods and can't do it. There is no place inside the flutter_reactive_ble repo at any stage of building where the .aar file resides (that I can find). If there were, I'd just replace it--that's the first thing I tried. I even tried looking for it in system caches. The only reference to it inside flutter_reactive_ble is the gradle.build file in a sub-project. Clearly, I need to find a gradle guy to fix that file.

Comment: The file you are looking for is at https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/blob/master/packages/reactive_ble_mobile/android/build.gradle

I think @Taz is right, you're going to have to fork the entire project and change the bits you need (see path above).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this in gradle:

```
configurations.each {
    c -> c.resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
            if (dependency.requested.group == 'com.polidea') {
                dependency.useTarget '<your grade plugin>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea what you intend me to fill in for "<your grade plugin>". The AAR file?  I've already forked the repo--should I go as far as to replace "com.polidea" with my domain everywhere in the code? Then still I don't know how Gradle looks for it--do I have to upload it to Maven or can I point to Github? I've been programming for 40 years, I'm sure I'm quite capable of doing whatever is necessary, I just don't want or need to take a month to learn Gradle for one project.

Answer (score 0):

It can be replaced alike this:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.polidea.rxandroidble2', module: 'rxandroidble'
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/rxandroidble.aar')
    // or depend on the module.
}
```

Comment: Built and ran, but doesn't appear to be using my AAR (it isn't showing the Logs I added). Might be other things in the way...I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to use your aar, then just declare it as dependency. Or you want the flutter_reactive_ble to use it? I don't think it's possible. You'd have to make pr to RxAndroidBle and then pr to flutter_reactive_ble to take that version in.

Answer (score 0):

I think overriding android dependency may solve your problem.

```
in build.gradle file of android project

configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
      force ‘<android library with specific version>’
   }
}
```

in your case:

```
force com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.11.1
```

check this link for [more detail](https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/flutter-dependencies-resolution-2faecdbfce03).

--------------------

for adding dependency of local project

in your `settings.gradle` file add mapping of your local project and include it

```
project(':local_project_name').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '<relative path of project>')

include ':local_project_name'
```

And then add a resolutionStrategy in your project's build.gradle file

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force implementation project(':local_project_name')
        }
    }
```

Comment: polidea's version is the one I DON'T want to use--I want to use the one I've compiled on my local drive.

Comment: please try my updated answer.